# Tests are running on my Ubuntu pc, but not on my Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3, Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 3.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, rspec, cucumber

I have project in Dropbox and two running laptops: one with Ubuntu and one with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3. When I try to run either rspec or cucumber on ubuntu they are running well, but when I try to run tests on Mac I have the same errors in 
***config/application.rb:13:*** `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))`

For cucumber:

```
Using the default profile...
undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `rescue in rescue in block in require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `rescue in block in require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
/Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/features/support/env.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
/Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/features/support/env.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/cucumber-1.1.9/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

For rspec:

```
No DRb server is running. Running in local process instead ...
/Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:77:in `rescue in rescue in block in require': undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `rescue in block in require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:62:in `block in require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global/gems/bundler-1.1.1/lib/bundler.rb:119:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/spec/spec_helper.rb:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/spork-0.9.0/lib/spork.rb:24:in `prefork'
        from /Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /Users/sergey/Dropbox/rails_projects/payforapps/spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:66:in `rescue in run'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:62:in `run'
        from /Users/sergey/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@payforapps321/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

How can I fix it? Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It means that projects are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in two gems in my **Gemfile**:

```
gem 'rb-inotify', '0.8.8'
gem 'libnotify', '0.5.9'
```

These gems are compatible only with Ubuntu as I understand.

**UPD:**

You should OS-specific gems to groups. Add all OS X specific gems to a ***darwin*** group in the Gemfile, and all Linux specific gems to a ***linux*** group:

```
# Gemfile
group :darwin do
  gem 'rb-fsevent'
  gem 'growl'
end

group :linux do
  gem 'rb-inotify'
end
```

To require the appropriate gems in the right environment, add the following to *config/application.rb*:

```
platform = RUBY_PLATFORM.match(/(linux|darwin)/)[0].to_sym
Bundler.require(platform)
```

See https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#bundler for more info about bundler here.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with my gem .

update the bundler

Read the error properly, it will tell you which gem is the culprit.

Thing is that not all gems are compatible with OS .

Comment: Yes, it's common issue. Thanks for additional explanation.